# threading example in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am basically trying to write a multicore version of mapreduce just to see whether i got the concept or not. And also wanted to learn threading in python as well.

I have lets say two chunks of text string.

How do I process them (let say tokenize them to words) simultaneously using multi-threads.
I thought I understood the docs, but this is one part (multithreading program) which one has to be very careful if it has to be efficient.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Threads in CPython (the standard Python implementation) aren't suitable for taking advantage of multiple cores, at least if you are writing pure Python code.  You should use multiple processes instead.

Comment: The issue you're going to run into is that Python does not really support multithreading. The global interpreter lock prevents two pieces of code from truly running at once.

Comment: I don't see a specific technical question of reasonable scope. "Show me an example of multi-threaded string tokenizing" isn't really on topic here. Once you've tried it and you hit a specific roadblock, ask about that.

Comment: @agf: yes sir..i understand. but atleast its good to gather ideas of something you dont know. (like multiprocess vs multithread) though i am completely aware of the QA format here. Thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: @agf You're absolutely right. Too bad though: I'd love to have a look at how this stuff should be done properly (look, someone's bookmarked it already. Not me :)). SO format is great for such things, as once someone proposes a flawed option, its drawbacks will be pointed to, and the votes will tell you if it's good.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Yeah, I read it several times making to make sure I wasn't jumping the gun. It's an interesting topic, but unfortunately the _question_ isn't quite right for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try using the `multiprocessing` module, and use its `map()` method.  This will let you use multiple cores efficiently.

Python threading is not as efficient as it could be because of time-consuming locking within the Python interpreter.  There is a `threading` module but you are probably better off with the `multiprocessing` module for map/reduce sort of problems.

Also, if you want to make sure you understand map/reduce, why not play with a real map/reduce system?  Hadoop is an available free-software map/reduce system and it is possible to use Python with Hadoop:

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

Comment: Hi. The code in that link.. is sequential in nature? right?? it is using just single core. right??

Comment: The code in that link is written for Hadoop.  Hadoop probably can be run on a single core for testing, but it is designed to be run on a cluster, and fan out the work to multiple computers all working at once.  You write your `mapper.py` (which probably runs on a single core) and your `reduce.py` (which probably runs on a single core) and Hadoop figures out how to parallelize the work across cores and/or computers.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop